# Integrating with the counting measure

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I have found the following example in a book, where the example emphasizes the importance of the fact, that the $\left(X,\mathscr{A},\mu_{1}\right)$ and $\left(Y,\mathscr{B},\mu_{2}\right)$ are have to be $\sigma$-finite measure spaces in the Fubini theorem.

Let me define the following measure spaces: $$\left(X,\mathscr{A}\right)=\left(Y,\mathscr{B}\right)=\left(\left[0,1\right],\mathcal{B}\left(\left[0,1\right]\right)\right),$$ where $\mathcal{B}\left(\left[0,1\right]\right)$ denotes the Borel sets of $\left[0,1\right]$. Let $\mu_{1}$ be the counting measure, $\mu_{2}$ be the Lebesgue measure. Let $f$ be the $\chi_{\Delta}$ characteristic function of $\Delta$, where $\Delta$ denotes the diagonal of the $\left[0,1\right]\times\left[0,1\right]$ unit square. In this case $$0=\int_{X}\int_{Y}fd\mu_{2}d\mu_{1}\neq\int_{Y}\int_{X}fd\mu_{1}d\mu_{2}=1.$$ I don't understand the example, because I don't understand how can we integrate $f$ over $X=\left[0,1\right]$ with the counting measure. How can we interpret it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful, as you are not integrating $f$ over $X=[0, 1]$. Instead, for every $b \in Y$, you are integrating $f_b(x)=f(x, b)$ over $X=[0, 1]$, as this is an iterated integral. (And then of course you are integrating $b \mapsto \int_X f_b \,\mathrm{d}\mu_1$ over $Y$.)

Now, this integral is not so difficult to compute: as $f_b(x)=1_{\{b\}}$ is the indicator function at $b$, we have
$$ \int_X f_b \,\mathrm{d}\mu_1 = \int_X 1_{\{b\}} \,\mathrm{d}\mu_1 = \mu_1(\{1\})=1. $$

Comment: So is it like $\int_{X}f_{b}d\mu_{1}=\int_{X}\mathbf{1}_{\left\{ b\right\} }d\mu_{1}=1\cdot\mu_{1}\left(B\right)$, where $B=\left\{ b\right\}$  a set with only one element (this element is $b$), and therefore $\mu_{1}\left(B\right)=1$, because $B$ has only one element?

Comment: ...But in this case I don't really understand the other integral. With the same train of thought, first I integrate $f_{a}\left(y\right)=f\left(a,y\right)$ over $Y$ for all $a\in X$. Therefore $\int_{Y}f_{a}d\mu_{2}=\int_{Y}\mathbf{1}_{\left\{ a\right\} }d\mu_{2}=1\cdot\mu_{2}\left(A\right)$, where $A=\left\{ a\right\}$  a set with only one element, so $\mu\left(A\right)=0$, because the Lebesgue measure of one point is $0$. ...

Comment: ...Then I integrate the constant zero function over $X$ with respect to the counting measure. So I want to integrate something over a set which is not countable ($X$) with the counting measure, and I don't know how can we integrate with the counting measure over a not countable set. I don't know if it makes sense. I wouldn't say for the left side is $0$. I would say it is undefined.

Comment: It's like $\int_{X}0d\mu_{1}=0\cdot\mu_{1}\left(X\right)=0\cdot\infty=?$ ...